# SQL query to delete charge and matching credit

Tags: sql

I have a table of transactions which contains an entry for both a charge and a reversal of that original charge. (Rather than delete the original charge, a reversal must be created to "balance out". Think accounting: charge and credit).

I need to create a SQL query that includes only valid line items/transactions. In other words, once a line entry is made and then a reversal created, I would want to EXCLUDE both the charge line and the reversal line in my end result.

I've seen several solutions that sum the transactions, which makes sense -- at an aggregate level it would all balance out.

However, for auditing purposes I need to return the line item detail.

Suggestions?

Comment: There are more questions here: 1. Can you give us the table schema? 2. What is the application you're using? (This sounds familiar) 3. How are the charge and the reversal connected? (start by answering these and we'll see where we can get)

Comment: Thanks Radu! I am writing the query in SQL. The table has the following fields: MbrID | TransactionDate | Charge | AuthorizationID | ReversalID.   In the Charge field the amount will be a negative amount if it is a reversal. Also, if it is a reversal, there will be a number in the ReversalID field. All other fields will be identical for both a charge and a reversal (MbrID, TransactionDate, AuthorizationID).

Comment: If there are multiple transactions for the same charge amount, how do you tell which transaction a reversal relates to? Do reversals use the same MbrID or is the ReversalID related to the original transaction? (or is it something else that relates them).

Comment: Is the AuthorizationID the primary key for the table? How do you relate the Reversal transaction with the transaction being reversed?

Comment: Yes, there may be multiple transactions for the same charge amount. Additionally there could be multiple reversals. You can't really tell which transaction the reversal applies to. Yes, they use the same MbrID.  There is currently no primary key for the table, but I could add when if necessary. There is no way to relate the reversal transaction to the transaction being reversed.

Comment: Illustration: 3 lines have identical MbrID, TransactionDate, Charge, and AuthorizationID. The charge amount is positive and the ReversalID is blank. Then 2 lines with identical MbrID, TransactionDate and AuthorizationID--BUT the charge amounts are negative and there is a ReversalID. I ultimately want to see 2 of the positive charges removed along with the 2 reversals, leaving only 1 single charge line.

Comment: If you can add a primary key, I would do that. Additionally, I would add a ReversedTransactionID and put the transaction being reversed into that column.

Comment: Ron Smith, you got me looking at something...you're a genius. Turns out the ReversalID actually does match the original AuthorizationID. I'm brand new to this data, so I didn't realize until you mentioned it. The challenge is still that I will only want to eliminate 4 out of the 5 lines, but adding the primary key may help with that.

Comment: @KSchmidt, you are too kind :) I'll update my answer to incorporate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to exclude anything with a ReversalID along with the matching Charge Transaction where ReversalID = AuthorizationID:

```
select
    t.MbrID,
    t.TransactionDate,
    t.Charge,
    t.AuthorizationID
from YourTable t
    left join YourTable r
        on r.ReversalID = t.AuthorizationID
where t.ReversalID is null
    and r.ReversalID is null
```